# Installing Cloud SDK and Python separately

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I want to install the Google Could SDK on a Windows 10 machine, but to install Python separately rather than using the bundled Python.

The instructions Google gives say you can do this, but they don't say if the pre-installed python needs to be x86, x86-64, or if it matters. What are the actual requirements?

Thanks,
    ++PLS

Comment: The SDK doesn't have a python bundled in it, you **need** to install python separately. If you mean something else please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the Google Cloud SDK is itself written in Python. The documentation only seems to specify which version that it requires (Python 2.7.9 or later) [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install). However, when it comes to which Python bit version to use, it depends on your end (as you would want to be compatible with the applications you want to run and the machine architecture you have running, etc).

As far as Google's SDK compatibility is concerned your system architecture should not matter. I have also tested the SDK on a vm-machine running  64-bit architecture with a 64-bit python version and it seems to work fine. Despite my test being a 64-bit environment, if you do have  x86-bit installed already the Google SDK should also not pose any issues for you.